# Why resolve method is not returning any data to the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I was following this tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BVo-72tgG0&index=41&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWKHkcL7RJmmXyxkuFB3KSl) and was trying to get the resolve method `getposts` into the contactController. I don't know why its not return any value.

Could someone tell me whats wrong i'm doing here. I had spent like an hour for this in stackoverflow, but no hopes :(

```
var app = angular.module('simpleApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: './partials/home.html'
  })
  .when('/contact', {
    controller: "contactController",
    controllerAs: "contactCtrl",
    templateUrl: './partials/contact.html',
    resolve:{
      getposts: function($http) {
        return $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1')
                    .then(function(response) {
                      // console.log(response.data) returns api data
                        return response.data;
        })
      } 
    }
  }).controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, getposts){

  vm = this;

  console.log(getposts); // not getting response.data from getposts

  vm.posts = getposts;

}])

// contact.html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    dfgdfg
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      {{ posts }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem 1: If i remove the two lines

```
controller: "contactController",
controllerAs:"contactCtrl"
```

and add `ng-controller="contactController"` in main div in `contact.html` i get an error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: getpostsProvider <- getposts <- contactController
```

Problem 2: if those controller and controllerAs lines are added and `ng-controller="contactController"` removed from view then i need to add
$scope to output posts to the view. If i do `vm.posts = getposts;` its not displaying json response in the view. Oh damn i'm confused.

Comment: actually it is not duplicate. `resolve` is part of Angular's $routeProvider setup not something related to `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: @skyboyer Yes even i was trying to dig my head with promises, await and aysnc. That was not the issue, the right answer Pankaj Parkar has provided below.

Comment: Are you instantiating the controller somewhere else with the `ng-controller` directive? In that case the `$compile` service will not see the local injected by the router.

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. The accepted answer answers the question of why the resolve method was not returning data to the controller. The second problem should be asked as a new question.

Comment: @georgeawg oops u felt my explanation as  a further question, i just wanted to elaborate the anomaly little further. And yes i instantiating the ng-controller inside the contact.html which was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you missed to inject `getPosts` inside inline array annotation of controller DI array.

```
controller('contactController', [
   '$scope', '$http', 'getposts', //<-- you missed to inject here
      function($scope, $http, getposts){
```

Comment: yes i have tried using 'getposts' in there, for some reason it was giving unknown provider getposts etc etc.. Now its working fine.

Comment: @rahul it could be if you make some typo in name. so Angular would try to find out what the service/factory/provider it is.

Comment: @skyboyer i have updated my question.